# Is there any satellite decoder system with SIM card that can extract and send the active channel PID or SID?

Tags: television, set-top-box, dvr, broadcast

Is there any satellite (free tv) decoder system with SIM card that can extract and send the active channel PID or SID? The system extracts the PID or identifiable id of the active channel to send it through a sms text to an extenal sms gateway.

I wonder if there is such a hardware so that one can record the tuned tv channel and the duration of viewing on some external database. Such a system will be very useful to measure the tv programming consumption behavior.